# SilverStripe unique URL (debug)

Tags: php, silverstripe

In this **DataObject** there is a user supplied field **Title** which has to be converted to a unique URL slug.

Desired Result: Duplicate URL's should get a suffix to its value. So saving 2 records with Title `Foo` should result in one record with `foo` as its value for column `URL` and the second record should have value `foo-2` for the same column.

```
public function onBeforeWrite() {
    parent::onBeforeWrite();

    // Sanitize Title field to use for URL
    $filter = URLSegmentFilter::create();
    $this->URL = $filter->filter($this->Title);

    // If URL is not unique, add suffix
    $i = 1;
    while($this->uniqueURL($this->URL)) {
        $i++;
        $this->URL = $this->URL . "-" . $i;
    }   
}
```

**method: uniqueURL** (within same class)

```
public function uniqueURL($URL) {

    // Check if there is a record with the same URL
    $existingURL = DataObject::get('NewsArticle', "URL = '$URL'");
    if ($existingURL) {
        // this is a duplicate URL
        return false;
    } else {
        // this is a unique url
        return true;
    }
}
```

Saving `Foo` twice would result in `foo` and `foo-2`.

When saving two records with the same Title `Foo` results in two URL fields with `foo`

Comment: What is your question,  does the first case needs to be `foo` and `foo-2` and second case as well ? or `foo-1` and `foo-2` in both cases?

Comment: `foo` for first and `foo-2` for second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why do you have two `foo` urls?**

If you check your DB before inserting all records, this means that the check will not work on your record batch.

**Don't use a loop to count unique urls**

You don't need to loop and check every time and increment the count (`$i`). Performance wise youre far better off doing a `COUNT()` in a query and just use that value for your next insert.

```
// The following does exactly the same with just 1 query. No loop needed.
$count = DB::query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Title LIKE '{$filteredTitle}'")->value();
if ($count > 1) {
    $filteredTitle .= "-" .  $count;
}
$this->URL = $filteredTitle
```

**Solutions**

To do it `onBeforeWrite()` the only possibility is to Query your data AND check your records before they are saved.

Or a simpler solution with the same results is that you can change the url in an `onAfterWrite()` , and check use the amount of same titles as number.

```
public function onAfterWrite() {
    parent::onAfterWrite();

    // Sanitize Title field to use for URL
    $filter = URLSegmentFilter::create();
    $filteredTitle= $filter->filter($this->Title);

    $count = DB::query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Title LIKE '{$filteredTitle}'")->value();
    if ($count > 1) {
        $filteredTitle .= "-" .  $count;
    }
    $this->URL = $filteredTitle
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. The `else` statement is necessary otherwise `$this->URL` would be NULL when it's unique.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you are absolutly right, I changed the answer for correctness. And it looks better now ;)